# When is a weak limit of martingales a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Suppose I have a sequence $\{X_t^n,{\cal F}_t^n\}$ of martingales (with respect to different filtrations), and suppose that $X_n$ converge weakly to a continuous process $X$. What are the conditions for $X$ to be a martingale with respect to its natural filtration ${\cal F}_t=\sigma(X_s,0\leq s\leq t)$?

In the problem I have in my research I can show that the $\{X^n\}$ are uniform integrable. So, in order to show $E[C_{t+u}1_A]=E[C_t1_A]$ for all $A\in{\cal F}_t$, I can show first
$$E[C_{t+u}g(C_s,0\leq s\leq t)]=E[C_{t}g(C_s,0\leq s\leq t)]$$
for all continuous and bounded $g$.

Then, I'm using the functional monotone class theorem ([link](https://almostsuremath.com/2019/10/27/the-functional-monotone-class-theorem/)); but I'm missing one step, which is to show that the $\sigma$-field generated by all bounded and continuous functions of $\{C_s,0\leq s\leq t\}$ is ${\cal F}_t$.
I'm pretty sure this is true but I don't know how to prove this. I think this will answer my question.

I hope this question makes sense...

Thanks

Comment: Well, you can always hope. But in order to speak of weak convergence, you might have the decency to define the range of $X_n$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks, I'm not sure I understand. Why is the range important when I talk about weak convergence? The martingales are not bounded, if this helps. They are, however, C-tight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the book:  "J. Jacod and  A. N. Shiryayev, *Limit Theory for Stochastic Processes*, 2ed. Springer, 2003'',
There is following result(p.522 Propsition 1.1): Assume that $ (M^n) $ is a sequence of martingales converging in law to a limit process $ M $, and that $ |M^n|\le b $
identically for some constant $ b $. Then $ M $ is a martingale with respect to the filtration that it generates.

Comment: thanks a lot! I wish there was a way to relax these conditions, for instance replace them with uniform integrability or finite m-th moments...

Comment: @Yonatan You are welcome. In Jocod's book, there are other sufficient condtions also,  e.g. in p.525 there is a proposition about the sufficiency of uniform integrability.